# How to set expire when using Redis geoadd

Tags: redis, geospatial

I am using the new geospatial features on Redis.
I know that behind the scene it's using ZSET.

I am adding new entries this way:

```
GEOADD" "report-geo-set" "4.78335244" "32.07223969" "jossef"
```

How could I add an expire to a specific records(in my case: "jossef")

on my set?

If the API doesnt provide it is there any workaround for this?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regrettably no - Redis expires entire keys and not the values in their respective data structures. Geo Hashes are implemented on top Sorted Sets and expiration of individual members isn't supported.

What you could do is maintain an additional Sorted Set and for each member in it store the expiration timestamp as score. Then, periodically, fetch the members that need to be expired from it based on ZRANGEBYSCORE and "manually" ZREM the respective members from your Geo Hash.

Comment: Gotcha. how do you delete a record from that geospatial by key ?

Comment: How in my example You would delete the record which contains "jossef"

Comment: `ZREM report-geo-set jossef` would do that for you

Comment: What I would do is add the timestamp to the member name in a json format "{'name':'jossef', 'timestamp':12121243424}", I can then parse the json and delete whatever I want. 

What do you think ?

Comment: That would make the deletion O(N) at the very least, and you won't be able to search for a member's location without prior knowledge of the entire JSON.

Comment: I don't get why it would be O(n), can you elaborate on that? Don't we just remove the value we just tried to get when it's outdated (so it would be O(1))? (I just started using Redis today so I don't get much yet, is ZREM struggling because of the added timestamp?)